# Justify text in a multirow

Tags: multirow

I have a problem when using long text with multirow  ! 
there is a code :

```
\documentclass[svgnames,french,english,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{m{8cm}m{5cm}m{3cm}}
\rowcolor{Gray}\multicolumn{1}{|L{8cm}}{Reporting}&&\\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{C{8cm}}{\multirow{3}{*}{Les fonctions de reporting permettent aux entreprises de consulter leurs données brutes, de les présenter sous la forme d'informations pertinentes et de les distribuer – à l'intérieur ou à l'extérieur de l'entreprise.}} & \ding{108} Crystal Reports & \multicolumn{1}  {R{3cm}|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Produits}}}\\
& \ding{108} Crystal Reports Explorer & \\
& \ding{108} Live Office & \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

and there is a screenshots that i would have :
[image]

but the result is like that :
[image]

Comment: Help mee please !!

Comment: Unrelated, but do not load `colortbl` if you also use the `table` option to `xcolor` as the latter internally loads the `colortbl` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any `multirow` environment, but a single row if you insert an `itemize` environment with convenient parameters in the second column:

```
\documentclass[svgnames,french,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }m{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\sffamily
\setlist[itemize]{wide = 0pt, label =\ding{118},leftmargin=*}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{tabular}{m{8cm}m{4.75cm}R{1.5cm}|}
\rowcolor{WhiteSmoke!80!Lavender}\multicolumn{3}{|l}{\bfseries Reporting} \\[1ex] \hline
\RaggedRight Les fonctions de \emph{reporting} permettent aux entreprises de consulter leurs données brutes, de les présenter sous la forme d'informations pertinentes et de les distribuer – à l'intérieur ou à l'extérieur de l'entreprise.
 & \begin{itemize}\raggedright
 \item Crystal Reports
 \item Crystal Reports Explorer
 \item Live Office
 \end{itemize} &
 \rotatebox[origin=r]{-90}{\color{LightSlateGrey!70}Produits} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you needed a `\parbox` around that text, as well as general reorganization.

```
\documentclass[svgnames,french,english,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{m{8cm}m{5cm}R{3cm}|}
\rowcolor{Gray}\multicolumn{3}{l}{Reporting} \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{8cm}{Les fonctions de reporting permettent aux entreprises de consulter leurs données brutes, de les présenter sous la forme d'informations pertinentes et de les distribuer – à l'intérieur ou à l'extérieur de l'entreprise.}} & \ding{108} Crystal Reports & \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{Produits}} \\
 & \ding{108} Crystal Reports Explorer &  \\
 & \ding{108} Live Office &  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I rotated your Produits in the other direction. If you prefer it the way you had it, then just change the `-90` to `90`.

Also can change `\ding{108}` to `\ding{118}` if you want the symbols in your example. See page 13 of [this document](https://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/LaTeX_symbols.pdf) for other options.

**Another option**

Here is another option that is a bit cleaner looking:

```
\documentclass[svgnames,french,english,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{1.5}%  1 is the default, change whatever you need
\begin{tabular}{|m{8cm}m{5cm}R{1cm}|}
\rowcolor{Gray}\multicolumn{3}{l}{Reporting} \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{8cm}{Les fonctions de reporting permettent aux entreprises de consulter leurs données brutes, de les présenter sous la forme d'informations pertinentes et de les distribuer – à l'intérieur ou à l'extérieur de l'entreprise.}} & \ding{118} Crystal Reports & \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{Produits}} \\
 & \ding{118} Crystal Reports Explorer &  \\
 & \ding{118} Live Office &  \\
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

slightly modified [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) answer. changes are indicated with `% <---`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames,french,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  % color names are defined with documentclass options
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{fancybox}                      % not used
\usepackage{pifont}

%\makeatletter                              % <--- superfluous
%\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}    % <--- superfluous
%\makeatother                               % <--- superfluous

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\sffamily
\setlist[itemize]{label=\ding{118},
                  leftmargin=*,
                  topsep= 0pt,                   % <---
                  after =\vspace{-\baselineskip} % <---
                  }
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}                    % <---
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}               % <---
\begin{tabular}{L{\dimexpr0.63\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-0.25\arrayrulewidth\relax}     % <---
                L{\dimexpr0.33\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-0.25\arrayrulewidth\relax}     % <---
                C{\dimexpr0.04\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-0.25\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}   % <---
\rowcolor{WhiteSmoke!80!Lavender}
\multicolumn{3}{|l}{\rule[-1ex]{0ex}{3.5ex}\bfseries Reporting}             \\      % <---
    \hline
Les fonctions de \emph{reporting} permettent aux entreprises de consulter leurs données brutes, de les présenter sous la forme d'informations pertinentes et de les distribuer – à l'intérieur ou à l'extérieur de l'entreprise.
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Crystal Reports
    \item Crystal Reports Explorer
    \item Live Office
        \end{itemize}   &   \rotatebox[origin=r]{-90}{\textcolor{LightSlateGrey!70}{~Produits}} % <---
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

[image]